# How to prevent undo steps being freed while undoing?

Tags: undo

As I understand it, undo operations (namely `undo` and `undo-only`) are regular Emacs operations which add to the undo history.

An issue with this is undoing adds to the size of the undo data, which could cause some undo data to be freed.

Is there a way to reliably pause this while the user runs `undo` & `undo-only`, restoring the normal freeing behavior once a regular editing operation runs?

---

#### Recipe that exemplifies the issue

Run the following command:

```
emacs -Q --eval "(setq undo-limit 1 undo-outer-limit 10 undo-strong-limit 10)" newfile.txt
```

Type in 8 characters over 6 lines, so the document reads.

```
AAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFF
```

Undo using `C-_` until only the first line is present.

```
AAAAAAAA
```

Now try redo by pressing `C-g`, `C-_` (keep pressing `C-_`).

The redo does not complete, it reaches 4 lines, then gives an error.

```
AAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDD
```

With the warning

```
Warning (undo): Buffer ‘newfile.txt’ undo info was 32 bytes long.
The undo info was discarded because it exceeded `undo-outer-limit'.
```

---

This is just to show that the undo history is freed while undoing.

Comment: Please provide a recipe, to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @Drew, added exact steps to redo the problem.

Comment: This sounds related to a recent suggestion on the Emacs devel mailing list wherein someone proposed `(let ((gc-cons-threshold most-positive-fixnum))
  ...)` around a function that operates on the undo-list to temporarily prevent GC from truncating the list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2020-01/msg00327.html  Eli Z. opines that GC should not be paused by the user ....  My take on the comments by Eli Z. is that GC should be permitted to do its thing ... as such, adjusting the undo-limits upwards may be about as good as it gets.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things much clearer.

Comment: However, it sounds like you answer your own question in the recipe. You set `undo-outer-limit` to a value that caused the behavior you lament. The doctor would say, I think, "If it hurts then don't do that." What is the real question, here? If you want to propose an enhancement to Emacs or report a bug, then `M-x report-emacs--bug`.

Comment: Note that I'm not all that happy with my own solution, I think its too fragile, although I didn't see a better way to do it either. Reducing the `undo-outer-limit` is just to show the behavior quickly, in real world use-cases undoing code refactoring (moving large blocks of text around) can still hit this issue, it's just less common. OTOH, if the problem can be avoided entirely... why not?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example implementation of a temporary lock which increases the limits while undoing.

This uses the `after-change-functions` to detect non-undo changes, releasing the lock.

Tested with emacs-27.

> *Note that I'm not all that happy with my own solution, I think the way it relies on hooks is fragile, although I didn't see a better way to do it either.*

```el
;; Undo Locking: don't free undo state while undoing.

;; These functions don't clear the lock even when they modify the buffer.
;; Include 'save-buffer' so hooks to format on save don't release the lock.
(defvar-local myundo--lock-dont-unlock-fn (list 'save-buffer 'undo 'undo-only))

;; When non-nil we have a lock, store undo limits here while locked.
(defvar-local myundo--lock-alist nil)

;; Override with 'let' so undo functions don't release the lock.
(defconst myundo--lock-dont-unlock nil)

(defun myundo--lock-disable-after-change (_beg _end _len)
  (unless myundo--lock-dont-unlock
    ;; Can be null since removing the 'after-change' doesn't happen immediately.
    (when myundo--lock-alist
      (myundo--lock-release))))

(defun myundo--without-lock-fn (old-function &rest args)
  (let ((myundo--lock-dont-unlock t))
    (apply old-function args)))

(defun myundo--lock-aquire ()
  ;; In case the lock was already enabled, re-enable.
  (when myundo--lock-alist
    (myundo--lock-release))

  ;; Prevent loss of undo data.
  (setq myundo--lock-alist
    (list
      (cons 'undo-outer-limit undo-outer-limit)
      (cons 'undo-limit undo-limit)
      (cons 'undo-strong-limit undo-strong-limit)))

  ;; Don't truncate any undo data in the middle of this.
  (setq undo-outer-limit nil)
  (setq undo-limit most-positive-fixnum)
  (setq undo-strong-limit most-positive-fixnum)

  (dolist (elem myundo--lock-dont-unlock-fn)
    (advice-add elem :around #'myundo--without-lock-fn '((name . "myundo--advice"))))

  (add-hook 'after-change-functions #'myundo--lock-disable-after-change :local)

  (message "Undo Lock Aquired"))

(defun myundo--lock-release ()

  (dolist (elem myundo--lock-dont-unlock-fn) (advice-remove elem "myundo--advice"))

  (remove-hook 'after-change-functions #'myundo--lock-disable-after-change :local)

  (setq undo-outer-limit (alist-get 'undo-outer-limit myundo--lock-alist))
  (setq undo-limit (alist-get 'undo-limit myundo--lock-alist))
  (setq undo-strong-limit (alist-get 'undo-strong-limit myundo--lock-alist))

  ;; Clear to show we're not locked.
  (setq myundo--lock-alist nil)

  ;; Account for reduced undo limits.
  (garbage-collect)

  (message "Undo Lock Released"))

(defun myundo--lock-aquire-advice (&rest _)
  (unless myundo--lock-alist
    (myundo--lock-aquire)))

(defun myundo--lock-install ()
  (interactive)
  (advice-add 'undo :after #'myundo--lock-aquire-advice '((name . "myundo--advice"))))

(defun myundo--lock-uninstall ()
  (interactive)
  (advice-remove 'undo "myundo--advice"))

;; Enable this now!
(myundo--lock-install)
```

Comment: I recommend you express your frustration via `M-x report-emacs-bug`, phrasing it as a request for feature.  E.g. the undo-truncation performed during GC could be tweaked such that the data is optionally moved somewhere where a package like "persistent undo" could make use of it.

Comment: I wonder why you don't do something like `(advice-add 'undo :around (lambda (origfun &rest args) (let ((undo-outer-limit nil) (undo-limit most-positive-fixnum) (undo-strong-limit most-positive-fixnum)) (apply origfun args))))`

Comment: I did this because I don't think I can guarantee the GC wont run. Wouldn't any edits to other buffers that run the GC also impact this buffer?

Comment: Those settings don't prevent running the GC, they control the effects of the GC instead, and they'd be active only during the execution of `undo`, which AFAICT is what you're talking about here.  I don't understand your last question (buffers don't run the GC).  But in any case, I recommend moving this elsewhere because the SX format is ill-suited for discussions.

Comment: Another case to increase these values is tools that format on save, I use `clang-format` on save for example. This would make saving loose undo history too. OTOH, what you suggest probably works well for many cases. I just wasn't sure when these values are used to limit undo.